# Unable to type once the Content Assist shell is popped up

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have attached a content assist to a text box by using the below code. The content assist is working fine.
But, once I press the 'Ctrl+space', then, All the proposals are displayed in a newly created shell.
Then, I try to type some more characters, but, I'm unable to type, as the new shell has the focus, not the text box.

Is there a way to minic, how the JDT editor does? Even after pressing the Ctrl+space and content proposals are displayed, we are able to type in the editor and the proposals are narrowed down based on the new characters.

```java
private void attachContentAssist(final Text propertyText) {
   ContentProposalAdapter contentProposalAdapter = new ContentProposalAdapter(propertyText, new TextContentAdapter(),
        this.proposalProvider, KeyStroke.getInstance("Ctrl+Space"), null);
   contentProposalAdapter.setLabelProvider(new ContentProposalLabelProvider());
   contentProposalAdapter.setPropagateKeys(false);
   contentProposalAdapter.setProposalAcceptanceStyle(ContentProposalAdapter.PROPOSAL_REPLACE);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```java
contentProposalAdapter.setPropagateKeys(false);
```

is stopping keys received while to pop-up is open being forwarded to the Text control, this is what is stopping the typing working.

Either specify `true` or remove the line as `true` is the default.